# html5/ Bootstrap site not playing embedded video on IOS devices, but works with everything else

Tags: html, ios, video

```
I have tried a few different variations but this is what i have currently. This code works on everything pc and android but NOT IOS. I also used IFRAMEs originally but had the same effect but it wouldn't let me embed the mov. file

<div class="container bg-white">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xl-8 "    style ="padding-top: 25px">

<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9  bg-secondary">

<embed 

src="video/IMG_6921_webm.webm" allowfullscreen   
src="video/IMG_6921_avi.avi"  allowfullscreen 
src="video/IMG_6921_mp4.mp4" allowfullscreen
src="video/IMG_6921_mov.mov" width="32" height="32">

</embed>

</div>
  
</div>
```

I tried using Iframes but had the same effect. The videos all play fine on Chrome, Opera, FireFox and edge and android and Kindle but not IOS(Apple products).`

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a tag `<video></video>`

Example: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp

Comment: Excellent! This worked for me

Comment: <div class="container bg-white">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-8 "    style ="padding-top: 25px">
    
    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9  bg-secondary">
 
  <video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="video/IMG_6921_webm.webm" type="video/webm">
  <source src="video/IMG_6921_mp4.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="video/IMG_6922.MOV" type="video/MOV">
  
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
    
</div>
    </div>